# Is the Turkish /n/ dental apical or dental laminal?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, turkish

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_phonology) the Turkish /n/ is dental, but it doesn't specify whether it's produced by the tip or the blade of the tongue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turkish grammars, like *Turkish Grammar*, 1976, by Robert Underhill or *Turkish Grammar*, 2nd edition, 2000, by Geoffrey Lewis, state that the Turkish /n/ is apical, produced with the tip of the tongue. 
Also note that the Turkish letter `n` preceding the letters `b` and `p` is pronounced as [m] (e.g. *İstanbul*) and when `n` precedes the letters `g` or `k` it is pronounced as [ŋ] (e.g. *Ankara*).